# node.js mongodb fail to connect sometime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have below code in node.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var appConfig = require('../appconfiguration');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(appConfig.db.connectionString, { useMongoClient: true});
```

**connectionstring is**

> mongodb://user:password@host/db?retryWrites=true

It is working fine, but sometimes at sudden, it stops working and throws an error

***Unable to connect host***

then again after sometime, it starts working again.

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you please post the value of appConfig.db.connectionString?

Comment: connection string updated

Comment: @KodandaRamaDurgaraopoluri post log on connection error